# Is this a common way of implementing a factory pattern in ObjectiveC?

Tags: objective-c

I'm studying some ObjC source here and one of the controllers has a property of type `NSDictionary` that is called "`overrideClassNames`".
As key it wants the class of an existing interface and as value the class of a subclass of the existing one, like:

```
controller.overrideClassNames = @{(id)[DefaultType class] : [MySubClassedDefaultType class]};
```

Whenever an instance of `DefaultType` is required, it would look up the dictionary and create a more specialized instance if one has been set.

I'm thinking if this is actually a common approach in ObjC? Coming from C# and Java, my idea would have been to create a delegate factory method that is called if an instance of `DefaultType` is required. The user of the class could then return his more specialized version.
Alternatively (in C#) I would make the class generic and let it have a `<T> : DefaultType, new()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this has not mainly to do with a factory pattern but with subclassing IMO -- BUT

yes. it is a common way to have a method that returns a class object - in osx for ex. A Control has a CellClass (which it allocs/inits to do the drawing for it)

and in a singleton you often have something like:

```
_sharedInstance = [[[self class] alloc] init];
```